# Simple partial differentiation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a simple partial differentiation question here, given:

$u = x^2 - y^2$ and $v = x^2 -y$, find $x_u$ and $x_v$ in terms of $x$ and $y$.

What is the easiest way to go about this?

Thanks

Comment: What partial derivatives are you looking for? $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$$, or the reverse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Think $x = x(u,v)$ and $y= y(u,v)$ and use implicit differentiation.

First we consider the partial w.r.t. $u$
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
\partial_u u &= \partial_u (x^2) - \partial_u (y^2),
\\
\partial_u v &= \partial_u (x^2) - \partial_u (y),
\end{aligned}\right.$$
this is:
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}
1 &= 2x \partial_u x - 2y\partial_u y,
\\
0 &= 2x \partial_u x  - \partial_u y.
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Now solve this equation for $\partial_u x$ and $\partial_u y$ in terms of $x$ and $y$:
$$
\partial_u x =\frac{1}{2x(1-2y)},\quad \partial_u y = \frac{1}{1-2y}.
$$
Now try to mimic above for the partial derivative w.r.t. $v$.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up an inverse Jacobian matrix,

$$ J^{-1} \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}u_x&u_y\\v_x&v_y\end{array} \right]  $$

and then use whatever method you like to produce its inverse, for instance,

$$ J \ = \ \frac{1}{\det J^{-1}} \left[ \begin{array}{cc}v_y&-u_y\\-v_x&u_x\end{array} \right] \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}x_u&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{array} \right] \ . $$

(This is not too much work when you only have two functions in two variables...)

For this problem, you'll have

$$ J^{-1} \ = \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}2x&-2y\\2x&-1\end{array} \right] \ \Rightarrow \ \left[ \begin{array}{cc}x_u&x_v\\y_u&y_v\end{array} \right] \ = \  \frac{1}{4xy-2x} \left[ \begin{array}{cc}-1&2y\\-2x&2x\end{array} \right] \ . $$

[Note that this technique is a "shorthand" for the algebraically equivalent method that **Shuhao Cao** shows.]

Comment: Nice answer, I thought this but then realized OP may not learn how to find the inverse of a matrix (Cal 3 is taught before Linear Algebra). +1

Comment: Where I am, linear algebra is part of Calculus III and multivariate calculus is IV.  Most of the "multivariate" texts I've seen introduce the Jacobian when it is needed.  (I'm perfectly happy to see various methods presented in the answers here at MSE -- you never know which ones will be helpful or obscure to the person posting the question or future readers.)